# Файлы ресурсов в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Необходимо в на стороне клиента создать подобие файла .resx в с#, для определения ресурсов приложения.

В данный момент, я храню все строки в MyRes.resx и передаю их на клиент следующим образом:

```
<script>
    var str = '@MyRes.SomeStr';
</script>
```

Из-за этого подхода у меня две проблемы:

1. Заключается в том, что строки которые я определяю в ресурсах на
   бекенде, используются только на стороне клиента;
2. Из-за большого кол-ва строк с ресурсами у меня получается довольно
   большая лента из присваиваний типа "var str = '@MyRes.SomeStr'.

Каким образом можно организовать хранение ресурсов на стороне клиента?
Или как можно по нормальному передать ресурсы на фронтенд?

Comment: Под ресурсами мы здесь имеем в виду только какие-то константы для локализации или что-то еще?

Comment: да, только константы.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужны только простые константы локализации только на клиенте, самый топорный способ сделать например папку Localizations, в ней файлы по типу localization.en.js, localization.ru.js, содержащие объект с нужными строчками.

```
var Localizer = {
    someParam: "Локализованная строка",
    dosmth : "Чета сделать"
};
```

Ну соответственно сервер отдает только нужный файл локализации (заголовки там смотрит, или какие-то внутренние настройки проекта, или клиент только его просит на основе своих настроек), а в скрипте пишешь `Localizer.someParam` когда надо к какому-то свойству обратиться.

Для большинства случаев этого достаточно, и основной принцип такой. Поверх можно навертеть полноценный менеджер локализации при желании.